# DevExpress MVC GridView Set Cell Image

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, gridview, devexpress, devexpress-mvc

In a DevExpress MVC GridView, I have defined a Column as "Status".

Example:
Status | Id | Name | IsValid

Depending on the boolean value of "IsValid", I want to show two different icons in the "Status" column for each record. How can I do this? And what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score -1):

I do not use DevExpress so I'm not sure how this would apply, but since you also specified gridview...

Typically you would handle this in the gridview rowdatabound event.

Status would be a `TemplateField` that has an `<ItemTemplate>` with a `<asp:Placeholder>` control and you would add appropriate img controls to hold the icons based on the IsValid field for each row.